# The derivative of the normal unit vector

Tags: geometry, differential

I want to derive the unit vector $N(s)=\dfrac{T'(s)}{\|T'(S)\|}$, where $T'(s)$ is the derivative of the tangent unit vector, how can I derive this vector?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! In order to maximize the chances of having a good quality answer, I suggest you had some details to your question. Specifically, you should explain what you have tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Omar the OP meant "differentiate" or simply "derive" as in "show that such-and-such is the case.  I assumed the former:

If the context is $\Bbb R^2$, i.e., the curves lie in the plane, then since $N(s)$ and $\kappa$ are defined via

$T'(s) = \kappa N(s), \tag{1}$

together with the requirement that $\Vert N(s) \Vert = 1$, where $\kappa$ is the curvature of the curve, it follows that

$N'(s) = -\kappa T(s);  \tag{2}$

you don't have to do any more work once you've got $T'(s)$; you're done.  A complete explanation may be found in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481718/a-curve-parametrized-by-arc-length).

If you're in $\Bbb R^3$, or even $\Bbb R^n$, $n > 3$ (1) still defines $\kappa$ and $N(s)$ in this case, and we can use it to write $N'(s)$ *via*

$T''(s) = \kappa' N(s) + \kappa N'(s), \tag{3}$

provided we can compute $\kappa'(s)$.  But

$\kappa(s) = \Vert T'(s) \Vert = \langle T'(s), T'(s) \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}, \tag{4}$

so that

$\kappa'(s) = \frac{1}{2}\langle T'(s), T'(s) \rangle^{-\frac{1}{2}}\langle T'(s), T'(s) \rangle' = \frac{1}{2}\kappa^{-1}\langle T'(s), T'(s) \rangle'. \tag{5}$

Now

$\langle T'(s), T'(s) \rangle' = \langle T''(s), T'(s) \rangle + \langle T'(s), T''(s) \rangle = 2\langle T'(s), T''(s) \rangle, \tag{6}$

so combining this with (5) yields

$\kappa'(s) = \langle T'(s), T'(s) \rangle^{-\frac{1}{2}}\langle T'(s), T''(s) \rangle, \tag{7}$

and now using (1) and (4) we see that

$\kappa'(s) = \kappa^{-1}\langle \kappa N(s), T''(s) \rangle = \langle N(s), T''(s) \rangle. \tag{8}$

(8) may be used in (3) which, after a little re-arranging, becomes

$N'(s) = \kappa^{-1}(T''(s) -  \langle N(s), T''(s) \rangle N(s)). \tag{9}$

That's most likely how I'd do it, in any event.  A "recipe" or set of directions for obtaining $N'(s)$ based on (9) might read:

Given $T(s)$,

1.)  Differentiate $T(s)$ to obtain $T'(s) = kN$; this gives $\kappa$ and $N$;

2.)  Differentiate $T'(s)$ to obtain $T''(s)$;

3.)  From the data derived in steps (1) and (2) above, algebraically calculate, in accordance with equation (9), $N'(s) = \kappa^{-1}(T''(s) -  \langle N(s), T''(s) \rangle N(s))$.

4.)  Halt.

Of course, it is also possible to compute $N'(s)$ directly from (1) by writing

$N(s) = \kappa^{-1}T'(s), \tag{10}$

reducing it to simplest terms "algebraically", and then differentiate the resulting expression directly.  But it's not clear that it would be less work the above prescpition; indeed, my personal experience shows it would often be more.  Addionally but not extraneously, the nice thing about (9) is that it breaks out everything in geometric terms; indeed, $T''(s) -  \langle N(s), T''(s) \rangle N(s)$ is the projection of $T''(s)$ onto $N^\perp(s)$, the subspace normal to $N(s)$.  So (9) has a nice interpretation, geometrically speaking:  it says that *the derivative of $N(s)$ with respect to $s$ is the component of $T''(s)$ normal to $N(s)$, divided by $\kappa$.*  One can of course assign similar geometric interpretations to most of the other equations occurring in the above discussion.

Of course all of the above is subject to the usual *caveats* concerning the vanishing of $\kappa$; we must generally assume we are working in a neighborhood where $\kappa(s) \ne 0$, since $N(s)$ can be defined, and the ensuing divisions by $\kappa$ are permitted.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and of course,

***Fiat Lux!!!***